# Passing a value from one view to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a button on an index page that links to a new_assignment_path

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Assign to Class', new_assignment_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

And I want it so that when you click on it, it takes you to the new_assignment_path, and takes the dropdown select on that pages form.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@assignment) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all.collect, as: :select %>
 </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And have the drop down automatically set to the user.id of whatever user the button was inside of.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: add params to your url `new_assignment_path(user_id: user.id)`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, I added the code for the full page. Do I need to specify the form somehow?

Comment: yes work with `params[:user_id]`

Comment: Where on the form do I add that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `params[:user_id]` in the selected option of your select tag

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all.collect, as: :select, :selected => params[:user_id] %>
</div>
```